# Mix 2 different guage of wire

Tags: electrical, switch, wire

I have exhaust fan and has no plug and the exhaust fan wire is too short, so I bought more wire but it's bigger than the existing wire. I'm planning to connect it to the light switch. Is this safe?

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]. It may be best to include a couple of pictures of your fan and some more details. You say "exhaust fan", and I think a bathroom or stove exhaust fan that's hard wired into the house wiring, but then you indicate that there's no plug, as though the plug has been cut off. Please clarify which situation. For in-wall wiring, so long as you're using the correct _type_ of wire, you can go to a bigger size (for example, you can use 12 AWG wire in a 15amp circuit where normally one would use 14AWG. Again, please [edit] your post to include some pics.

Comment: Can you post photos of the existing fan and its wiring please?

Comment: Generally speaking, it's fine to use a slightly larger wire size. It's not fine to use smaller. For a more definitive answer, please respond to the comments above. Also try to find your period key for next time. :)

Comment: I agree with Isherwood as long as the box fill is not exceeded and all connections are made in boxes larger wire is ok.  Well the wire has to be rated for the location also.

Answer (score 0):

You can freely mix wire gauges as long as the smallest (the existing wire, in your case) is thick enough to be safe.

Comment: Yep.  Going to a **smaller** wire would be an issue!